# Magento 2 issue with merge JS ( Some JS only work with hard refresh after enable marge JS)

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am facing one issue when I enable merge JS see below details.

I have one JavaScript which is adding button into the webpage, this script is working fine with default loading of the JavaScript but when I enable merge
JS and set production mode then this JS is only work while I hard refresh page (Ctrl + Shift + R).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact error in your console. Did you added your js as per magento standard?

Comment: Hello @SaurabhDwivedi, no error in the console and yes js I added as per the Magento standard.

Comment: Can you post your "JavaScript which is adding button" and causing issue?